# How do I type-hint a Vector of Strings in Clojure?

Tags: types, clojure

My function returns a sequence, for example Vector of Strings.

Here is a trivial example (which in practice would be derived from type inference, but which illustrates the point):

```
(defn ^PersistentVector myfunction [a b] 
    ;; do something with strings
)

(my-function  ["A" "B"])
```

How do I type-hint this to show that these are specifically  Strings?

Something like `^PersistentVector<String>`?

Comment: Your `defn` statement is not legal syntax. What are you trying to do?

Comment: If you are interested in "optional typing" to document & verify argument & return types, you may be interested in Plumatic Schema: https://github.com/plumatic/schema

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A [`PersistentVector`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentVector.java) can contain objects of any type, there is no way to enforce the type of the content, so a notation for such a type hint does not exist. You can have it return a Java array of strings and then you can use the convenience type hint `(defn ^"[Ljava.lang.String;" function [a b])`:

```clj
(defn ^"[Ljava.lang.String;" function [a b]
  (into-array String [a b]))

(type (function "a" "b"))
;; => [Ljava.lang.String;
```